# Regarding "User setup for Windows" what should I do after download?

Tags: visual-studio-code, settings

I just upgraded vscode on windows 10 to v 1.26.1. A popup came up & said,
"We recommend switching to User Setup distribution of Code for Windows. Click [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_26#_user-setup-for-windows) for more info."

Well i clicked & it said to download and i did. The page said,"If you are a current user of the system-wide Windows setup, you will be prompted to switch to the user setup, which we recommend using from now on. **Don't worry, all your settings and extensions will be kept** during the transition."

Then when i ran the downloaded .exe a popup comes up & says
[image]

So now I am worried. Are you folks **sure** my settings, etc. will be preserved if i click yes?

Comment: This isn't a duplicate. The identified duplicate is about how to proceed with the upgrade while this question is confirming that preferences will be preserved.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, i'm sure.

> User setup for Windows Announced last release, the user setup package
>   for Windows is now available on stable. This setup does not require
>   Administrator privileges to install. It also provides a smoother
>   background update experience.
>
> If you are a current user of the system-wide Windows setup, you will
>   be prompted to switch to the user setup, which we recommend using from
>   now on. Don't worry, all your settings and extensions will be kept
>   during the transition.

https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_26#_user-setup-for-windows

Comment: So to clarify, we are saying if I completely uninstall VSCode first, then install the User setup, then I should be good to go? This is actually pretty scary.

Comment: @MartavisP. Very scary indeed, but i did it successfully. A piece of cake.

Comment: yes worked well for me and I did not loose any settings..

Comment: @Martavis P. You don't necessarily need to uninstall VSCode yourself. Just make sure all instances of VSCode are closed. The update installer will handle un-installation plus install.

Comment: Thank you guys for the input :-) I'll be upgrading soon